# Refreshing Google Id_token received via firebase google authentication

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication, google-authentication, refresh-token, angular-social-login

In Angular/React when we do google authentication using firebase we get below object.

[image]

Under credential we have idToken which google issues and expires in 60 minutes.
How to refresh this token to get a new one .

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the provided Firebase Auth SDK, You don't have to do anything to refresh the token.  The SDK will do that automatically.